# ssrs external image from ashx

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to get a dynamic image loaded into SSRS 2005 from a handler.  The handler works fine, when I set an asp:image src to it, it works as expected.  When I add an image to an SSRS 2005 report and set the value explicitly in the value it shows the image in the designer.  This is a local report being displayed in a ReportViewer control.  When the site is run (via localhost) the image src is empty.

Comment: Alright, it was my fault and not SSRS.  Being so wrapped up in working with a charting control I never set the response type.